# Concatenating List Elements in Pandas DataFrame from different columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data set in the form as mentioned below:
[image]

The data set is in the form of a list in each cell in the columns.
Input:

```
type(df['Hospitals][0])
```

Output:

```
str
```

I would like to access individual elements in each cell in both the columns, and further concatenate the elements at respective list index in both the columns.

For eg:

```
In: df['Hospitals][0]

Out: [' Wockhardt Umrao ', ' Seven Hills Hospital ']

In df['Address][0]

Out: [' Mumbai, India ', ' Mumbai, India ']
```

Then the final Expected result in new colmns is -

```
['Wockhardt Umrao, Mumbai, India',' Seven Hills Hospital, Mumbai, India']
```

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

you can directly concat the dataframe columns, check this out.

```
data = [['tom', 'u.s'], ['nick', 'u.k'], ['juli', 'ind']] 
  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 

df['NeW'] = df['Name'] + ',' + df['Age']
print(df)
```